# Where is the ALT+UP/DOWN (move line) setting in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I installed `Resharper 2017` for **VS2017**, in the first run it asked about hotkey setup and I chose VS hotkeys. I tried `Resharper` and decided to uninstall it. Now <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> / <kbd>DOWN</kbd> doesn't move lines! How can I fix it? What option should I check.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok. I found it in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp(Down)